# The measure of the closure of borel measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given lebesgue measure $m$ on $\mathbb R^n$, I am interested in whether $m(E) = m(\overline E)$ for all $E$ and why.

In general, if $E$ is bounded, then by observing the $\overline E \subset U$ \implies $E \subset U$ for all open $U$, and since $m(E) = \inf_{E \subset U, \text{ U open}} m(U)$ the claim is proven for bounded E$.

What if $E$ is unbounded?

Comment: Take $n = 1$. What if you set $E = \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: It doesn't generally hold for bounded $E$ either. $E\subset U$ does not imply $\overline{E}\subset U$.

Answer (score 2):

Choose any dense subset $A$ of $[0, 1]$ that does not have full measure, such as $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$; then $\overline{A} = [0, 1]$ and $$m(\overline{A}) = 1 > m(A)$$

---

In fact, *any* countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ leads to a counterexample to the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. Let $V$ be any non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^n.$ Then $E=V\cap \Bbb Q^n$ is of measure zero, but $\overline E$ has positive measure. Note that this is true whether or not $V$ (so $E$) is bounded, so your claim is not generally true even then. The best you can say (using your reasoning) is that $m(E)\le m(\overline E),$ which is true for any Lebesgue measurable set $E,$ bounded or otherwise.